# Discord.py mass dm bot

Tags: python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I've been trying to find out a way to make a discord bot dm everybody inside of my server. I have already found a question similar to mine and tried the answer but it didn't work. My current code looks like this

```
  if message.content.upper().startswith('.MSG'):
      if "345897570268086277" in [role.id for role in message.author.roles]:
        member = discord.Member
        args = message.content.split(" ")
        if member == "@everyone":
          for server_member in server.members:
          await client.send_message(server_member, "%s" % (" ".join(args[1:])))
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use the commands extension for this, not `on_message`

```
# import stuff we'll be using
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.utils import get

# Bot objects listen for commands on the channels they can "see" and react to them by 
# calling the function with the same name

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='.')

# Here we register the below function with the bot Bot
# We also specify that we want to pass information about the message containing the command
# This is how we identify the author
@bot.command(pass_context=True) 
# The command is named MSG
# The `, *, payload` means take everything after the command and put it in one big string
async def MSG(ctx, *, payload):   
    # get will return the role if the author has it.  Otherwise, it will return None
    if get(ctx.message.author.roles, id="345897570268086277"): 
        for member in ctx.message.server.members:
            await bot.send_message(member, payload)

bot.run('token')
```

How sure are you that `"345897570268086277"` is the role id? It might make more sense to search for it by name.

Comment: I can add some comments.  It might be useful for you to read the [documentation of `discord.ext.commands`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/rewrite/ext/commands/commands.html) in the meantime.  The documentation is for the experimental branch, but the general structure is identical.

Comment: Thanks, but when I replaced my old code and tried it nothing happened, can you tell me what each part of your code does because that would help me understand what might be the problem.

Comment: Yeah that would help.

Comment: I added some comments.  Ask if you have any more questions.  I also forgot to add `bot.run` to the original version, so it never actually ran the bot.

Comment: In my code I used `client.run('token')` and at the beginning instead of `bot = commands.Bot(commands_prefix='.')` I used `client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='.')` will it still work the same?

Comment: as long as you also replace all the other references to the `bot` object, yes.

Comment: Once I run it it says this error message
discord.errors.Forbidden: FORBIDDEN (status code: 403): Cannot send messages to this user